# How can you make each word in a tkinter label a button?

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, text, label

I have a tkinter label containing the first letters of each word of a text to memorise. How can I make each of these letters (separated by spaces) into buttons which reveal the original word when pressed?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a label rather than a button?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want the text to wrap at a certain length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a label for each word. If you remove the border and pack them together it will look like they are a single label.

For each label, bind a function to the mouse button, and in that function you can change the text of the label. You can associate the word with the label object so that you can easily access it in the bound function.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def reveal(event):
    label = event.widget
    label.configure(text=label.full_text)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x100")
word_frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
word_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20, pady=20)

term = "Impossible Mission Force"
for word in term.split():
    letter = word[0].upper()
    label = tk.Label(word_frame, text=letter, borderwidth=0, 
                     font=("Helvetica", 18))
    label.full_text = word
    label.pack(side="left")
    label.bind("<1>", reveal)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can I make the labels pack in rows within the frame so they look like text? I am working with whole paragraphs of text.